# zoom in/out images in c#

Tags: c#, image-processing, zooming

Any one know the corresponding C# code of [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/PanZoomExample.aspx?display=PrintAll&fid=345111&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=26)

Comment: Is there a specific part of the code you're having an issue with or are you just wanting someone to convert it all to c# for you?

Comment: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I do. Are you asking for someone on here to translate that *entire* VB.NET project into C# for you? That isn't likely to happen for free.

Instead, might I suggest that you try an automated conversion tool, like [this one](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/), or [this other one](http://converter.telerik.com/)?

But really, any competent C# programmer should be able to translate VB.NET code into C# with a little bit of effort. The only thing that's changed is the syntax; the underlying methods are all exactly the same. Anyone who assumes experience with the .NET Framework should be fluent in either language.

Comment: The second option seems very good, I will try to translate it myself. Thanks for your motivation.